# Do I need armeabi-v7a along with arm64-v8a on playstore w.e.f 1st August 2019?

Tags: android

My android app had only 32 bit support for arm architecture (only contained  armeabi-v7a lib in .apk), now since we need to provide [64 bit support](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) as well, I built my app with arm64-v8a, so right now it has only arm64-v8a libs and no armeabi-v7a that goes along, in the .apk (only targeting arm devices above lollipop Android 5.0). Will this prove to be a blocker for re-launching my app on playstore, considering the norm 1st August onwards ? Will my app fit the bill ?

Comment: `Will my app fit the bill ?` Yes, but you don't have to remove armeabi-v7a

Comment: Could'nt agree more, but the kind of setup I'm using only builds for one arm architecture at a time, I'd have to build for an armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a seperately, then extract the libs and sign again with something, like apksigner or something...